# Calling a method from a different class to another class & method

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors, bluej

I have two classes, one called Driver and another called BankAccount. In Driver there is a method called Driver, and in BankAccount a method called Deposit. I'm getting an error that says, "non-static method Deposit() cannot be referenced from a static context" when I try to call BankAccount.Deposit from my Driver method.

Any advice on what I should do to these lines of code to make it run.

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Driver
{
    int choice;
    String number;
    //public Driver()
    public Driver()
    {
         String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. Deposit 2. Withdraw 3. Balance 4. Change name 5. Exit");
         int choice = Integer.parseInt(number);
         do
         {
         if( choice == 1)
         {
             BankAccount.Deposit() = new Deposit();
             Driver.Driver = new Driver();
            }else if(choice == 2)
          {
              BankAccount.Withdrawl = new Withdrawl();
              Driver.Driver = new Driver();
            }else if(choice == 3)
            {
               BankAccount.getBalance = new getBalance();
               JOptionPane.showDialog(balance);
               Driver.Driver = new Driver();
            }else if(choice == 4)
            {
                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Please enter a name");
                Driver.Driver = new Driver();
            }else if(choice ==5)
            {
                JOptionPane.showDialog("Goodbye" + name);
            }
        }while( choice >= 1 && choice <= 5);
}
}
```

here is the BankAccount Method

```
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class BankAccount
{
double balance = 400;
double deposit;
double withdraw;
double Interest = 1.05;
String name;
String accountNumber;

public BankAccount()
{
name = null;
accountNumber = null;
balance = 0;
}

public double Deposit()
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to deposit?");
    deposit = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if (deposit < 10000)
    {
        balance = (deposit + balance);

    }
    return balance;
}

}
```

Comment: `new Deposit()`? Is `Deposit` a _class_? Where and how is it defined?

Comment: As many times as this has been said on this site already - you should *definitely* consider picking up, or re-reading, an introductory Java text. The number of errors in your code is ... significant.

Comment: Search for the similar questions first. See these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=non-static+method+Deposit%28%29+cannot+be+referenced+from+a+static+context+[java]

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you have written your code like this.

Method name in java should start with a small letter like `deposit` and not `Deposit`.

`BankAccount` is a class and `Deposit` is a non-static method in it.

So for using `Deposit` method you must first create an object/instance of your `BankAccount` class like this :

```
BankAccount b =new BankAccount();
```

And then use any method using that object reference :

```
b.Deposit();
b.Withdraw();
```

You should write it like this :

```
if( choice == 1)
{
     BankAccount b = new BankAccount();
     b.Deposit();
}
```

Same you need to do for withdraw and other

```
else if(choice == 2)
{
     BankAccount b = new BankAccount();
     b.Withdrawl();
     Driver.Driver = new Driver();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
BankAccount.Deposit() = new Deposit();
```

makes no sense. First, `Deposit()` is an *instance* method of `BankAccount`. It only makes sense to call it for a particular instance of `BankAccount`. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

Beyond that, there's the problem that `Deposit()` returns an `int` value, which is not something that can appear on the left side of an assignment statement. Also, you don't mention any class named `Deposit`, so I don't know what `new Deposit()` is supposed to be.

You seem to have similar problems further on in your code. For instance, the next statement:

```
Driver.Driver = new Driver();
```

is utter nonsense—there is no field `Driver.Driver`.

I recommend that you read the tutorial [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

a working version of your 'intention' :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Driver
{
    int choice;
    String number;
    BankAccount myAccount=null;

    public Driver()
    {
    myAccount=new BankAccount();
    }

    public void drive()
    {
    String number = "";
        int choice = 0;
        String name = "?";
         do
         {
             number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. Deposit 2. Withdraw 3. Balance 4. Change name 5. Exit");
             choice = Integer.parseInt(number);
         if( choice == 1)
         {
             myAccount.Deposit();
            }else if(choice == 2)
          {
          // mAccount.Withdrawl();
          // missing method Withdraw1()
            }else if(choice == 3)
            {
        // BankAccount.getBalance = new getBalance();
        // missing method getBalance()
        // JOptionPane.showDialog(balance);
            }else if(choice == 4)
            {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Please enter a name");
        // todo i guess name should be used somewhere in bankaccount... like myAccount.setName(name)
            }else if(choice ==5)
            {
                // JOptionPane.showDialog("Goodbye" + name);
        // no showDialog method in JOptionPane
        return;
            }
        }while( choice >= 1 && choice <= 5);
    }

    public static void main(String pArgs[])
    {
    Driver driver=new Driver();
    driver.drive();
    }
}
```